# What's the easiest way of getting Magic Coins in The Sims: Makin' Magic?

Tags: the-sims

I want a house in the magic quarters. What's the easiest way of getting Magic Coins, including cheat codes?

Answer (score 2):

Duelling Vicki Vampiriess and winning awards you Magicoins. According to [this page](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/simsmm.html#.T8K3ltVYsg0), the maximum output is 40 coins per duel. [IGN cheats](http://ca.ign.com/cheats/games/the-sims-makin-magic-pc-569957) gives some pointers on how to beat Vicki Vampiriess:

- If she casts Blue Tornado, cast Red Wave or White Lightning;
- If she casts Yellow Brimestone, cast Black Blizzard or Blue Tornado;
- If she casts Red Wave, cast Yellow Brimestone or White Lightning;
- If she casts Black Blizzard, cast Red Wave or Blue Tornado;
- If sh casts While Lightening, cast Yellow Blizzard or Black Blizzard.

Also according to IGN, you can evict a family from their home and move them back in. When you do so, the Mystery Man will come to your house and drop a Magico starter kit which contains 35 Magicoins. You can save the coins and do this as often as you like.

You can also go to Magic Town with a Sim with maximum logic and perform on stage all day long. The maximum output from this method for a day appears to be 675 Magicoins.

As a side note, a Sim can only carry 32,767 Magicoins at once, and MagiCo's Bookshelf of Dimensional Storage will only hold 30,000. ([Source](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/MagiCoins))

Comment: I've found all these by Googling. So which one is the _easiest_ (i.e. fastest)?

Comment: @Anna Those *are* the easiest ways. At this point it depends on *your* gameplay and how *you* like to play the game. Do you have a full logic Sim? If so, performing might be the best for you if you don't mind having it doing only that all day. Or you might prefer actually doing stuff, then duelling could be better *for you*. No full logic? It would seem evicting is the best then. Try them out and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to improve your logic and mechanical skill until full when they don't want to do it just save and enter cheat code move_objects on. So when they tired of ut you just delete the sim. If your logic and mechanical full go to the magic town and go to the place that have a mummy or whatever, do the spectral spouses, the magic storm, and the mummy's tomb all over again, fast foward it until your sim don't want to do maximum magicoins that you achieve are 40 to 47. Just once you do it,you will get 100 or more.then go back to your house use the hole, and do it all over again. Or you just can duel with someone but it will take a while.there's many advantage if your logic and mechanical skill so it's faster just use the mummy thingy.I have moving into the house in the magic town for 4 time.